# Order of precedence with batch and Powershell statements

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(%%I); $date.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy') >c:\temp\datas
```

I would like to run the above command in the following order

1-  Replace the %%I with the current value, lets say -1

2- Run the powershell command as follow

```
PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
```

3- Put the  result the the file C:\temp\datas

Can it be done?

Comment: Where are you getting the `%%I` from? It sounds like you may just want use pure PowerShell for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you simply tried that? It works fine, although it is quite slow. I assume you really want to use append mode, otherwise your file never gets more than one row.

```
@echo off
for /l %%I in (-10, 1, 10) do PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(%%I); $date.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy') >>c:\temp\datas
```

The following more complicated form also works. I'm not sure when this form is needed

```
@echo off
for /l %%I in (-10, 1, 10) do PowerShell -command "&{$date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(%%I); $date.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')}" >>c:\temp\datas
```

Calling PowerShell for each iteration is very slow because it takes time for PowerShell to load each time. It would be much faster if you put the loop within PowerShell.

Another option that would work more efficiently with a batch loop is to use my [GetTimestamp.bat hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847):

```
@echo off
for /l %%I in (-10, 1, 10) do call getTimestamp -od %%I -f "{mm}-{dd}-{yyyy}" >>c:\temp\datas
```